# Is there any performance gain when using features from C# 6.0?

Tags: c#, performance, compilation, c#-6.0

Do C# 6.0 features (like expression-bodied method-like members, `using static`, null-conditional operator or string interpolation) have any impact on the performance of a program or at least the compiling time? I like the new features but I was asking myself when using them if there is any performance gain/issue.

Comment: Yes.  The programmer can be slightly more performant.

Comment: They are just minor syntax sugar features, make no difference at runtime.

Comment: I'll bet you won't be able to measure any difference in compile times.

Comment: The only thing I can think of that could be more performant is the `nameof` operation. It'll surely be better than using reflection to get a name.

Comment: C# 6 gives the product team a chance to migrate from the native compiler to Roslyn based managed compiler, so it's feature set has been carefully chosen and it seems to be focusing on language sugar as other comments said. Compilation might be faster or slower based on your code as the new compiler does behave differently. The generated MSIL should be similar but might not exactly the same. That might also impact performance but the impact might be subtle.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Not really. The new features are merely syntactic sugar for things already possible in C#.

The code generated by the new features, like the null-propagation operator, eventually yield the same C# code as you would already have had before.

It does make *you* better performing and possibly the code quality better, which is a good thing.

Comment: https://www.simple-talk.com/dotnet/.net-framework/whats-new-in-c-6/ would be a good reference from the guys on .NET Reflector.